# SwiftUI and CoreData: Switch between FetchedResults based on user input

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

Can I have a variable @FetchRequest? I Have two different entities that have some overlapping properties that I show in a subview. I have entityDescription change between based on user input and would like the @FetchRequest to return the correct entity.

If this is not possible, how can I accomplish the desired behavior? Do I need to make a superclass for my two entities: CfTexture and CfColor? I think from a modeling standpoint, it doesn't make sense for them to be subclassed from an abstract entity, but maybe it makes sense functionally to do it this way.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ScrollGridView: View {
    
    // Managed object context from environment
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    // Entity for fetch request
    @State var entityDescription: NSEntityDescription
    
    // Fetch unlocked CfColor or CfTexture from Core Data
    @FetchRequest(entity: entityDescription,
                  sortDescriptors: [
                    NSSortDescriptor(
                        keyPath: \name,
                        ascending: true)],
                  predicate: NSPredicate(format: "isUnlocked == 1"))

    // What do I put here?
    private var category: FetchedResults<CfColor>
```

Comment: Check out [`FetchRequest.Configuration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/fetchrequest/configuration).

Comment: You can't use a single FetchRequest for different entities. You could create a protocol with the common properties that both types conform to and then use that protocol as the data source type in your sub view

Comment: @Coder-256 Thanks. That's what I needed. How do I filter a fetch request with a predicate specifying the child entity I want? Do you know the correct key path?

Comment: You can not do that. The only time you can access another entity in a predicate is when you have a relationship between it and the main entity which is not the case here as I understand it.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I did end up making a superclass of these two entities using by checking the Abstract Entity box and assigning it as the parent entity in the Core Data model. Now, I was able to use ```NSPredicate("entity == %@", MyEntity.entity())``` to filter the right subentry @JoakimDanielson

Comment: That is one way to go but I would recommend you to learn more about protocols and try to use them instead of inheritance so you don't have to change your model design just to solve a UI problem.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks. I will look into doing this. For this method, I would need two separate FetchRequests though right (to get both Core Data entities) before combining them to pass the protocol-conforming array to the subviews?

Comment: You haven't shown your CoreData model, but it may be that you want to rethink your model. If you have entities with the same parameters, it may make more sense to declare those parameters as `Relationships` instead. Then you can simply traverse the relationship, rather than fetching and attempting to combine two similar, but different entities.